# Looking for an interesting result on the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, navier-stokes

I am in my second year of master in Mathematics and one of my courses consists of a reading of *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Roger Temam. We have proven the existence for the weak Stokes and Navier-Stokes (defined on a bounded domain) in a stationary and non-stationary regime using a Galerkin method.

Now I have to do a 2 hours presentation on the subject of my choice (still related to hydrodynamics) and I would like to know if one of you had an idea of something I could talk about. I looked on the internet for an article that could match my critera but all I found was way too advance or too long for what I am looking for. I am looking for a paper that could be presented in two hours, that is accessible to a master student (who has read Temam's book) and that is an important result in the modern understanding of the Navier-Stokes equations (a paper by Leray, Ladyzhenskaya, Fujita-Kato, Lions, ... for example). Could one of you, who has a better knowledge of what has been done in hydrodynamics, give me some advice on this subject?

I first asked the question on Stackexchange Mathematics but I don't know which site is best for what I'm looking for. You may find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419791/looking-for-an-interesting-result-on-the-navier-stokes-equations) my question on Stackexchange Mathematics.

Comment: No one should listen to a 2-hr presentation, so this sounds like a poor assignment. I doubt the other students can benefit from listening to student presentations of longer than 15-20 minutes. It sounds like your professor is shirking their teaching duties.

Comment: This *Quanta Magazine* article could help: [Mathematicians Coax Fluid Equations Into Nonphysical Solutions](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-coax-fluid-equations-into-nonphysical-solutions-20220502/).

Comment: @MattF. On the other hand, a student *can* benefit a lot from **(preparing and) giving** a two-hour-long presentation (I speak from experience here).

Answer (score 23):

Beale Kato Majda criteria: Beale, J. Thomas, Tosio Kato, and Andrew Majda. "Remarks on the breakdown of smooth solutions for the 3-D Euler equations." Communications in Mathematical Physics 94.1 (1984): 61-66.

Provides a necessary condition for blowup, used frequently in modern research on NS (1500+ citations) and is only 6 pages long (!).

Answer (score 20):

What about a talk on uniqueness theorems for classical solutions? This problem was settled by [Emanuele Foà](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuele_Fo%C3%A0) (1929) and [David Dolidze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Dolidze) (1954), who succeded independently in proving uniqueness for bounded domains (Serrin gives a brief description of their work in [1], p. 251, footnote 1 and [2] p. 271): their proof is nothing more than a clever use of [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality). Later [Dario Graffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dario_Graffi) succeded in extendig their theorem to unbounded domains, under various supplementary conditions. The Wikipedia entries linked above and the main references listed below could give you a basic bibliography: finally, regarding Graffi's contribution, the main reference is [1] which is in Italian, but the topic is also dealt extensively in the monograph [2] (precisely chapter 4), written in English, and which also deals with the results for bounded domains.

**Edit**

[In his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419588/looking-for-an-interesting-result-on-the-navier-stokes-equations/419602#comment1077733_419602) Calvin Khor has pointed out that a digitized version of [2] is available from the borrowing service of the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/): I have embedded the link he found into reference [2] and gratefully thank him for the notification.

**References**

[1] Dario Graffi, "Sul teorema di unicità nella dinamica dei fluidi" [On the uniqueness theorem in fluid mechanics], Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata, IV Serie (in Italian), 50: 379–387, (1960), [DOI: 10.1007/BF02414524](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02414524), [MR0122198](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0122198), [Zbl 0102.41103](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0102.41103).

[2] Dario Graffi, *[Nonlinear partial differential equations in physical problems](https://archive.org/embed/nonlinearpartial0000graf)*, Research Notes in Mathematics, vol. 42, Boston–London–Melbourne: Pitman Advanced Publishing Program, pp. IV+105, ISBN 978-0-273-08474-7, [MR0580946](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0580946), [Zbl 0453.35001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0453.35001).

[3] James Serrin, "Mathematical principles of classical fluid mechanics", in Flügge, Siegfried; Truesdell, Clifford A. (eds.), *Fluid Dynamics I/Strömungsmechanik I*, *Handbuch der Physik (Encyclopedia of Physics)*, vol. VIII/1, Berlin–Heidelberg–New York: Springer-Verlag, pp. 125–263, (1959), [DOI: 10.1007/978-3-642-45914-6_2](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-45914-6_2), [MR0108116](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0108116), [Zbl 0102.40503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0102.40503).

[4] James Serrin, "On the Uniqueness of Compressible Fluid Motions", Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis, 3 (1): pp. 271–288, (1959b), [DOI: 10.1007/BF00284180](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF00284180), [MR0106646](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0106646), [Zbl 0089.19103](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0089.19103).

Comment: It seems that [2] can be "borrowed" from [the Internet Archive for free](https://archive.org/details/nonlinearpartial0000graf)

Answer (score 6):

You could consider talking about sufficient conditions for energy conservation. There are two I know that are 'easy'. Firstly there is Shinbrot's [1] condition (Leray-Hopf solution $u\in L^p_t L^q_x$ for $\frac2p+\frac2q=1$ conserves energy). The paper is written well (Shinbrot in general is a good writer), and a recent short paper [2] extended this result with elementary techniques.

Secondly, in the ideal case $\nu=0$, there is the 'rigid' part of the Onsager conjecture, which is a theorem of Constantin, E, and Titi [3]: it asserts that even distributional solutions conserve energy if they belong to $L^3 B^{\alpha}_{3,\infty}$ for some $\alpha>1/3$ (In particular if they belong to $L^3 C^{0,\alpha}$.)

The above mentioned papers are all quite short. The 'flexible' part of Onsager's conjecture was recently [4] solved (more or less, but this is still actively researched)  but IMO would be too technical and need more than 2 hours. Still, you might want to consult e.g. the survey [5].

---

[1] *Shinbrot, Marvin*, [**The energy equation for the Navier-Stokes system**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0505092), SIAM J. Math. Anal. 5(1974), 948-954 (1975). [ZBL0316.76011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0316.76011).

[2] *Beirão da Veiga, Hugo; Yang, Jiaqi*, [**On the Shinbrot’s criteria for energy equality to Newtonian fluids: a simplified proof, and an extension of the range of application**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.na.2020.111809), Nonlinear Anal., Theory Methods Appl., Ser. A, Theory Methods 196, Article ID 111809, 4 p. (2020). [ZBL1437.35525](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1437.35525).

[3] *Constantin, Peter; E, Weinan; Titi, Edriss S.*, [**Onsager’s conjecture on the energy conservation for solutions of Euler’s equation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02099744), Commun. Math. Phys. 165, No. 1, 207-209 (1994). [ZBL0818.35085](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0818.35085).

[4] *Isett, Philip*, [**A proof of Onsager’s conjecture**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2018.188.3.4), Ann. Math. (2) 188, No. 3, 871-963 (2018). [ZBL1416.35194](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1416.35194).

[5] *Buckmaster, Tristan; Vicol, Vlad*, [**Convex integration and phenomenologies in turbulence**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/EMSS/34), EMS Surv. Math. Sci. 6, No. 1-2, 173-263 (2019). [ZBL1440.35231](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1440.35231).

Answer (score 6):

You could choose a paper by the same author as the book you have studied. A particular short and nice one concerns the incompressible Euler equations:

- Roger Temam, On the Euler equations of incompressible perfect fluids, Journal of Functional Analysis, Volume 20, Issue 1, 1975, Pages 32-43, ISSN 0022-1236,
  https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(75)90052-X.
  (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212367590052X)

The methods you learned will make it accessible to you and your audience.

A motivation for choosing this paper could be further research interest in the direction of so-called inviscid limit problems: do solutions to Navier-Stokes equations converge to solutions to an Euler equation when the viscosity parameter tends to zero(especially in bounded domains this is very interesting, keyword: boundary layers).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following papers will be helpful: [Some open questions in hydrodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2336) and [Between Hydrodynamics and Elasticity Theory: The First Five Births of the Navier-Stokes Equation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41134138).

Another option would be to talk about Arnold's result that solutions to Euler's equations correspond to geodesics on the infinite-dimensional Riemannian manifold of volume preserving diffeomorphisms: [Geometric Hydrodynamics: from Euler, to Poincare, to Arnold](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03301).